# Embedded Array from Post Array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

So this probably very simple but I can seem to get it to work on my end. I currently have an embeded array that looks like this:

```
$array = array (
    array(
        $_SESSION['Contact']['Name'],
        $_SESSION['Contact']['Email']
        ...
    )
);
```

My session array has about 30 fields in it. Using the example above, I would have to list out every session array item manually. So, my questions is, is there a way to iterate over the Sessions array to get the same above outcome.

```
$array = array (
    array(
       foreach ($_SESSION as $key => $value){
         $value.", ";
       }
    )
);
```

//My Email/CSV Functions

```
function create_csv_string($data) {

  // Open temp file pointer
  if (!$fp = fopen('php://temp', 'w+')) return FALSE;

  // Loop data and write to file pointer
  foreach ($data as $line) fputcsv($fp, $line);

  // Place stream pointer at beginning
  rewind($fp);

  // Return the data
  return stream_get_contents($fp);

}

function send_csv_mail ($csvData, $body, $to = 'xx@xxx.com', $subject = 'Test email with attachment', $from = 'zz@zzz.com') {

  // This will provide plenty adequate entropy
  $multipartSep = '-----'.md5(time()).'-----';

  // Arrays are much more readable
  $headers = array(
    "From: $from",
    "Reply-To: $from",
      "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$multipartSep\""
  );

    // Make the attachment
    $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(create_csv_string($csvData)));

    // Make the body of the message
    $body = "--$multipartSep\r\n"
        . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1; format=flowed\r\n"
        . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n"
        . "\r\n"
        . "$body\r\n"
        . "--$multipartSep\r\n"
        . "Content-Type: text/csv\r\n"
        . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"
        . "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"file.csv\"\r\n"
        . "\r\n"
        . "$attachment\r\n"
        . "--$multipartSep--";

    // Send the email, return the result
    return @mail($to, $subject, $body, implode("\r\n", $headers));

}

send_csv_mail($array, "Hello World!!!\r\n This is simple text email message.");
```

Comment: Why would you bury the session array like that?

Comment: Im using it to creat a CSV file and then email myself the results.

Comment: Can't you just create CSV without having to bury the session variables?

Comment: IDK, im a newbie. I pasted my function above. I found this function online and it worked so I just stuck with it.

Comment: Is the problem that you have nested arrays?  Your example shows a single $_SESSION['contact'], but is there also a $_SESSION['contact2'] and $_SESSION['contact3'], each of which has the members 'Name' and 'Email'?

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured this out. Simple answer and was almost too obvious.

```
$array = array (
        $_SESSION['Purchase']
);
```